# Why the program can't find the file? python thanks

Tags: python, os.path

The code:

[image]

I'm trying to open this file but Python doesn't find it.

```
    import os ,shutil, re , random
```

```
        #categoria a caso
        cat= random.choice(categorie)
        
        string = str(input("Inseriisci nome utente e password\n"))  
        string=string+" "+cat
       
        lista = open((os.path.join("rubrica", "lista.txt")), "a")
        lista.write(f"\n{string}")
        lista.close()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\progetti\base_allenamento\rubrica\accounts.py", line 30, in <module>
    lista = open((os.path.join("rubrica", "lista.txt")), "a")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rubrica\\lista.txt'
```

I have no idea about how to solve the problem.

Comment: Please follow the stack overflow question guidelines

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]. We expect you to put effort into your questions.

Comment: It would be nice if you put your code here in text instead of using an image.

Comment: yeah sorry, that's a really good idea I should have done in  this way in the first place

Comment: either using absolute path or open("lista.txt") will solve your problem. Even if you are joining rubrica with the file you are not telling it where the rubrica is. os.path.join("..\rubrica", "lista.txt")  this is not a good way though.

Answer (score 0):

If your accounts.py file is in the same folder as the file you're trying to open, you don't need to use os.path, you can simply do:

```
lista = open('lista.txt', 'a')
```

Comment: That is not always the case. The CWD can be anything and is not guaranteed to point to the directory of the started python application. It's best to use absolute pathes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your file structure looks something like this

```
- rubrica (folder)
---- accounts.py (file)
---- lista.txt  (file)
```

You need to search for `lista.txt` **relative** to your script `account.py` which is a **sibling**. So the correct would be either of these

```
lista = open("./lista.txt")  # this works
# or list = open("lista.txt")
```

What you are instead doing by calling `os.path.join("rubrica", "lista.txt")` is searching for **ANOTHER** folder named `rubrica` that is a **SIBLING** to your `account.py` file, which simply does not exist.

```
>>> os.path.join("rubrica", "lista.txt")
'rubrica/lista.txt'

# Here is how it is searching
# - rubrica (folder)
# ---- accounts.py (file)
# ---- lista.txt  (file)
# ---- rubrica (folder)  Here it is looking next to account.py for rubrica
# -------- lista.txt     this does not exist
```

Comment: ``open("./lista.txt")  # this works`` That is not always the case. The CWD can be anything and is not guaranteed to point to the directory of the started python application. It's best to use absolute pathes instead.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I've solved the problem, thank you

Comment: @Mike Scotty that is correct when your are running files as modules (eg `python -m mymodule.script`) or you are running another file that is importing that. In this case the OP is running the file using `path/to/python path/to/file.py`, in which searching for the relative path is valid.

Comment: @Countour-Integral ``open()`` will try to open relative pathes relative to the current working directory (it even says so in the docs), so if your command line looks like this ``/tmp>path/to/python path/to/file.py`` then the CWD should be ``/tmp`` and thus the file will be searched as ``/tmp/lista.txt`` (for both ``open("./lista.txt")`` and ``open("lista.txt")``, at least that's what I can also reproduce in my windows system by looking at ``os.getcwd()``. So while your answer may be correct, there are cases where the CWD is set differently and you should thus not rely on it.

Comment: @Mike Scotty isn't  your example the exact case here? There is a folder `rubrica` which has inside it a file `accounts.py` and by running `python accounts.py`, `./lista.txt` is trying to access `rubrica/lista.txt`, which is a sibling. In your case there is `tmp/` which has inside it `file.py` and `list.txt` and trying to acess `./list.txt` from `file.py` will result in `tmp/list.txt` which is the sibling of `file.py`.Of course `os.getcwd()` is different depending on how the script is used (either imported by something else and/or used as a module).

Comment: @Countour-Integral No, in my example ``/tmp`` is supposed to be a random directory that is **different** from the directory where ``file.py`` and ``lista.txt`` reside. Ofc, if it's the same, then it works, but if your CWD does not contain your main python file then relying on relative paths is bound to fail - and thus it's safer to use absolute paths.

Comment: Windows example: ``C:\users\mike>python D:\projects\test\accounts.py`` The CWD is ``C:\users\mike`` - and that's not even on the same drive as my main python file, so building relative paths will fail if the assumption is that the file I want to open resides in ``D:\projects\test``

Comment: @Mike Scotty Now I see what you mean. The CWD when running like this, is the directory from which the script was run .It's really easy for the `import` system to cause issues like this. Unfortunately we can't use really use absolute paths (we'll have to use `os.getcwd()`  again or relative paths) when we have to deal with  creating modules that are installed `pip` or just anything that will be used by different people with different machines. This could be mentioned in the answer, but there are even more ways you can cause the same problems and having to list them all is just not worth it.

Comment: Exactly. Don't get me wrong, I didn't mean to prove your answer wrong, I only wated to point out that there are scenarios where it could still fail, which is why absolute paths are safer. You could try to build absolute paths using the module's magic ``__file__`` attribute.